# Can I initialize elements with an additional default-parameter using std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, containers

I'm currently working on my own little framework which has the following design pattern:
Each object inherits from LObject and has a parent which it informs when something has changed in the object.
Here's an example:

```
class LObject
{
public:
    LObject(LObject* const _pParent = nullptr) :
        _mpParent(_pParent),
        _mChildrenCount(0)
    {
        if(parent() != nullptr)
            _mChildId = parent()->GenerateChildId();
    }

    unsigned int id() const { return _mChildId; }

protected:
    LObject* const parent() const { return _mpParent; }

    unsigned int selfId() const { return -1; }
    unsigned int GenerateChildId() const { return _mChildrenCount++; }

    virtual void ChildChanged(unsigned int _childId)
    {
        if(parent() != nullptr)
            parent()->ChildChanged(id());
    }
    virtual void ChildChanged() const
    {
        if(parent() != nullptr)
            parent()->ChildChanged(id());
    }

private:
    LObject* const _mpParent;
    unsigned int _mChildId;
    mutable unsigned int _mChildrenCount;
};

template <typename T>
class LType : public LObject
{
public:
    /// constructors
    LType(LObject* const _pParent=nullptr) : 
        LObject(_pParent),
        _mValue() 
    {}
    LType(const T& _rcValue, LObject* const _pParent=nullptr) :
        LObject(_pParent),
        _mValue(_rcValue)
    {}

    /// template type
    typedef T size_type;

    /// modify data
    void set(const T& _rcValue, bool _notifyParent=true)
    {
        _mValue = _rcValue; 
        if(_notifyParent) 
            ChildChanged();
    }
    void add(const T& _rcValue, bool _notifyParent=true); // same with +=

    /// get data
    const T& operator()() const; // returns _mValue

    /// operators (modify / get data)
    void operator=(const T& _rcValue); // same as set

private:
    T _mValue;
};

class SomeObject : public LObject
{
public:
    SomeObject(LObject* const _pParent = nullptr) : 
        LObject(_pParent), 
        someInt(this) 
    {}    

    LType<int> someInt;

    virtual void ChildChanged(unsigned int _childId)
    {
        LObject::ChildChanged();

        if(_childId == someInt.id())
            std::cout << "someInt changed!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SomeObject obj;
    obj.someInt = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

Output: someInt changed!

Now I want to implement a container class, which should work like this:

```
class SomeOtherObject : public LObject
{
public:
    SomeOtherObject (LObject* const _pParent = nullptr) : 
        LObject(_pParent), 
        someContainer(this) 
    {}   

    LContainer<LType<int>> someContainer;

    virtual void ChildChanged(unsigned int _childId)
    {
        LObject::ChildChanged();

        if(_childId == someContainer.id())
            std::cout << "someContainer changed!" << std::endl;
        if(_childId == someContainer[0].id())
            std::cout << "someContainer[0] changed!" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SomeOtherObject obj2;
    obj.someContainer.push_back(5);
    obj.someContainer[0].set(32);

    return 0;
}

Depending on the implementation the output should be: 
someContainer changed!
someContainer[0] changed!
or 
someContainer changed!
someContainer changed!
```

(For the time being i don't care if the elements of the container are children of the container or if they have the same parent as the container.)

So as you see I want the container to work like std::vector, the only difference is, that objects that are created in there (with push_back or with insert) know their parent and that the container knows it's parent.
(Maybe I don't even care about the container knowing it's parent but I think it's mandatory)
In the best-case scenario I'd like to just use std::vector.

I didn't find any clues of a feature like a default value that's passed at the end of the std::vector::push_back parameter list in the cplusplus reference.
So my Questions:

- Is a way and I just didn't find it?
- if no, is there an easier way than completely reimplementing std::vector?

I want a container class for my little framework with as little implementations of allready existing methods from the STL as possible.

I'd like to implement it like that (if at all possible)

```
class LContainer : public std::vector, public LObject
{
    LContainer(LObject* const _pParent) :
        LObject(_pParent)
    {
        std::vector::addValuesWithDefaultParameter(parent()); // If something like that is available)
    }
};
```

Edit: This is how i solved the problem.
I inherited from both LObject and std::vector and reimplemented the few functions that added something to the vector.
Notice: private inheritance is used to prevent users from typing `obj.container.std::vector::push_back(element);`

```
/// LContainer.h
template <typename T>
class LContainer : public LObject, std::vector<T>
{
public:
    LContainer(LObject* const _pParent=nullptr);
    LContainer(unsigned int _startSize, LObject* const _pParent=nullptr);
    LContainer(unsigned int _startSize, const T& _rcValue, LObject* const _pParent=nullptr);

    /// Iterators
    using std::vector<T>::begin;
    using std::vector<T>::end;
    using std::vector<T>::rbegin;
    using std::vector<T>::rend;
    using std::vector<T>::cbegin;
    using std::vector<T>::cend;
    using std::vector<T>::crbegin;
    using std::vector<T>::crend;

    /// Capacity
    using std::vector<T>::size;
    using std::vector<T>::max_size;
    void resize(unsigned int _newSize, const T& _rcValue);
    using std::vector<T>::capacity;
    using std::vector<T>::empty;
    using std::vector<T>::reserve;
    using std::vector<T>::shrink_to_fit;

    /// Element access
    using std::vector<T>::operator [];
    using std::vector<T>::at;
    using std::vector<T>::front;
    using std::vector<T>::back;

    /// add elements
    void assign(unsigned int _count, const T& _rcValue);
    void push_back(const T& _rcValue);
    using std::vector<T>::pop_back;
    void insert(unsigned int _position, const T& _rcValue);
    void insert(unsigned int _position, unsigned int _count, const T& _rcValue);
    using std::vector<T>::erase;
    using std::vector<T>::swap;
    using std::vector<T>::clear;
    using std::vector<T>::emplace;
    using std::vector<T>::emplace_back;

    /// Allocator
    using std::vector<T>::get_allocator;

private:
    T _mElementDummy;
};

/// LContainer.inl file
template <typename T>
LContainer<T>::LContainer(LObject* const _pParent) :
    LObject(_pParent),
    std::vector<T>(),
    _mElementDummy(_pParent)
{}
template <typename T>
LContainer<T>::LContainer(unsigned int _startSize, LObject* const _pParent) :
    LObject(_pParent),
    std::vector<T>(),
    _mElementDummy(_pParent)
{
    while(std::vector::size() < _startSize)
        std::vector::push_back(_mElementDummy);
}
template <typename T>
LContainer<T>::LContainer(unsigned int _startSize, const T& _rcValue, LObject* const _pParent) :
    LObject(_pParent),
    std::vector<T>(),
    _mElementDummy(_pParent)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;

    while(std::vector::size() < _startSize)
        std::vector::push_back(_mElementDummy);
}

template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::resize(unsigned int _newSize, const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::resize(_mElementDummy, _mElementDummy);
}

template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::assign(unsigned int _count, const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::assign(_count, _mElementDummy);
}
template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::push_back(const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::push_back(_mElementDummy);
}
template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::insert(unsigned int _position, const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::insert(_position, _mElementDummy);
}
template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::insert(unsigned int _position, unsigned int _count, const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::insert(_position, _count, _mElementDummy);
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps some example code of what you would like to see will help.

Comment: added an example code at the end.

Comment: Note that `_mChildId` is not initialized when `parent() == nullptr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 That's fine, _mChildId is only used when a parent is available

Comment: @Gamer2015: its getter is available from public interface, so user may use it...

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, I'll initialize it with something

Comment: It seems like the parent of anything pushed to a container should be the container itself, not the container's parent. You really only need to write custom implementations for std::vector methods that add new elements, and even then you only need to implement what you plan to use. In other words, maybe just write a custom `push_back` for now and defer to std::vector for everything else.

Comment: @Austin Mullins, yeah you're right. the std::vector class is not as big as i had imagined, I'll just reimplement those methods.

Comment: a private member variable makes your code easier to read than private inheritance

Comment: @MattMcNabb yeah that might be the case but I think it's the better and easier to implement solution for this problem.
I don't have to implement each std::vector method (which makes the *.inl file shorter) and because of the inheritance most of the methods are used directly from the STL which makes it easier to use.
Furthermore, inheriting lets me point directly to the cplusplus reference for detailed explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector::push_back` does not have the ability to take an additional parameter.

My suggestion:

1. Use composition instead of inheritance from `std::vector` to define `LContainer`.

   ```
   class LContainer : public LObject
   {
       LContainer(LObject* const _pParent) : LObject(_pParent)
       {
       }

       // Member variable 
       std::vector<LObject*> containedObjects_;
   };
   ```
2. Add a function in `LContainer` to add objects. In this function, use `std::vector::push_back` and then do the necessary additional processing.

   ```
   class LContainer : public LObject
   {
       LContainer(LObject* const _pParent) : LObject(_pParent)
       {
       }

       void addObject(LObject* object)
       {
          containedObjects_.push_back(object);

          // Do the additional processing.
          // ...
          //
       }

       // Member variable 
       std::vector<LObject*> containedObjects_;
   };
   ```

Comment: I'll just go with this as there really aren't that many methods to implement.

Comment: @R Sahu, I solved it differently  (edited question and posted solution at the end). I think my solution is better for my case and therefore I don't want to keep your answer as "accepted" but answering to my own question feels wrong, should i still answer my own question and accept my answer? (is it possible to accept my own answer?)

Comment: @Gamer2015, yes, I haven't done it but I think it is OK to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to inherit from both LObject and std::vector and reimplemented the few functions that added something to the vector.

Functionality from std::vector was taken with the keyword using.

Notice: private inheritance is used to prevent users from typing `obj.container.std::vector::push_back(element);`

```
/// LContainer.h
template <typename T>
class LContainer : public LObject, std::vector<T>
{
public:
    LContainer(LObject* const _pParent=nullptr);
    LContainer(unsigned int _startSize, LObject* const _pParent=nullptr);
    LContainer(unsigned int _startSize, const T& _rcValue, LObject* const _pParent=nullptr);

    /// Iterators
    using std::vector<T>::begin;
    using std::vector<T>::end;
    using std::vector<T>::rbegin;
    using std::vector<T>::rend;
    using std::vector<T>::cbegin;
    using std::vector<T>::cend;
    using std::vector<T>::crbegin;
    using std::vector<T>::crend;

    /// Capacity
    using std::vector<T>::size;
    using std::vector<T>::max_size;
    void resize(unsigned int _newSize, const T& _rcValue);
    using std::vector<T>::capacity;
    using std::vector<T>::empty;
    using std::vector<T>::reserve;
    using std::vector<T>::shrink_to_fit;

    /// Element access
    using std::vector<T>::operator [];
    using std::vector<T>::at;
    using std::vector<T>::front;
    using std::vector<T>::back;

    /// add elements
    void assign(unsigned int _count, const T& _rcValue);
    void push_back(const T& _rcValue);
    using std::vector<T>::pop_back;
    void insert(unsigned int _position, const T& _rcValue);
    void insert(unsigned int _position, unsigned int _count, const T& _rcValue);
    using std::vector<T>::erase;
    using std::vector<T>::swap;
    using std::vector<T>::clear;
    using std::vector<T>::emplace;
    using std::vector<T>::emplace_back;

    /// Allocator
    using std::vector<T>::get_allocator;

private:
    T _mElementDummy;
};

/// LContainer.inl file
template <typename T>
LContainer<T>::LContainer(LObject* const _pParent) :
    LObject(_pParent),
    std::vector<T>(),
    _mElementDummy(_pParent)
{}
template <typename T>
LContainer<T>::LContainer(unsigned int _startSize, LObject* const _pParent) :
    LObject(_pParent),
    std::vector<T>(),
    _mElementDummy(_pParent)
{
    while(std::vector::size() < _startSize)
        std::vector::push_back(_mElementDummy);
}
template <typename T>
LContainer<T>::LContainer(unsigned int _startSize, const T& _rcValue, LObject* const _pParent) :
    LObject(_pParent),
    std::vector<T>(),
    _mElementDummy(_pParent)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;

    while(this->size() < _startSize)
        std::vector::push_back(_mElementDummy);
}

template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::resize(unsigned int _newSize, const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::resize(_mElementDummy, _mElementDummy);
}

template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::assign(unsigned int _count, const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::assign(_count, _mElementDummy);
}
template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::push_back(const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::push_back(_mElementDummy);
}
template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::insert(unsigned int _position, const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::insert(_position, _mElementDummy);
}
template <typename T>
void LContainer<T>::insert(unsigned int _position, unsigned int _count, const T& _rcValue)
{
    _mElementDummy = _rcValue;
    std::vector::insert(_position, _count, _mElementDummy);
}
```